# Trick NSWindow into showing as active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I trick an NSWindow as displaying as active, without activating the application itself?

(The reason is that I wish to somehow trick Cocoa into doing that temporarily while I take a "screenshot" of the window.

It's very difficult to do this through all the methods I've experimented with, because things always happen not instantly but "soon". For example, I can't just activate the app, take the screenshot, and re-activate the previously active app, because "activate app" is an operation that just happens "sometime in the future", i.e. the app doesn't wait for the operation to finish before continuing. So it's all very tricky.)

Comment: To be clear, is this window one belonging to your application, or some other application?

Comment: It belongs to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any good way to do this properly

Answer (score 3):

Worth a try:

```
NSDisableScreenUpdates();
...activate app/window, take screenshot, deactivate
NSEnableScreenUpdates();
```

Comment: I suspect this might fail because the screenshot code probably reads from the frame buffer, which is not current at that point if you disable screen updates. However, this is just speculation.

Comment: I've used these calls in the past, and the usual screenshot methods apparently read from the window's backing store. NSDisableScreenUpdates() should just prevent that store being used to update the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In case of scriptable applications you can simply use AppleScript:

```
-- Get name of frontmost application at front
set active to name of (info for (path to frontmost application))

-- Activate specific application to take the screenshot from
tell application "Safari" to activate

-- Take screenshot and save it to the desktop
do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of ((POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "Shot.png") as string

-- Make the previous frontmost application again frontmost
tell application active to activate
```

Use `NSAppleScript` within Cocoa:

```
NSString * source = @"set active to name of (info for (path to frontmost application))\n"
"tell application \"Safari\" to activate\n"
"do shell script \"screencapture -tjpg \" & quoted form of ((POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & \"Shot.png\") as string\n"
"tell application active to activate";

NSAppleScript *theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
[theScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical of this because this will probably cause some "blinking" between different apps while the screenshot is being taken. I was hoping it was somehow possible to just do this with actually tricking the window to show as active, i.e. not to actually "legally" activate it.